# printing of header in Indiatimes website fails

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit4, browser-automation

I am trying to print the header "The Times of India" in the website "https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/us" but it fails..I think the problem is the popup notification which asks to give an input... I tried alert but that doesn't help... can someone help me in fix the code below..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WebDriver driver = utils.HelperFunctions2.createAppropriateDriver("Chrome");
        
        driver.get("https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/");
        System.out.println("****Main page loaded*****");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
        String header = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"header-masthead\"]/div/a/img")).getText();
        System.out.println(header);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because "The Times of India" is a **Picture**, not a **Plain text**! Webdriver can not interpret image as a text.

What you can do in this case is to check *attribute* `"src"`:

```
String titlePicture = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"header-masthead\"]/div/a/img")).getAttribute("src");
```

It should be equal to `https://static.toiimg.com/photo/77144633.cms` - source of "The Times of India" picture

Comment: So whats your suggestion on getting the text "The Times of India" from the page...how do i get this text and print it.. thats my objective

Comment: @JeyanthiRanjit you need [OCR (optical character recognition) tool (like Tesseract)](https://towardsdatascience.com/read-text-from-image-with-one-line-of-python-code-c22ede074cac) to "read" text from image